# Proof involving generating function

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, generating-functions

The following is part of a proof that the number of ways of associating a product with $n$ terms (different ways of inserting parentheses) is $$
a_1 = 1,\ a_n = \frac{1}{n} \binom{2n-2}{n-1},$$
and the relationship$$
a_{n+1} = a_1a_n + a_2a_{n-1} + a_3a_{n-2} + \cdots + a_na_1$$
is already established.

The proof starts with the generating function $$f_A(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n,$$
then by the relationship, $$f_A(x) = x + \sum_{n=2}^\infty (a_1a_{n-1} + \cdots + a_{n-1}a_1)x^n.$$
I am unclear about the next step:
$$f_A(x) = x + \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n\right)\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n\right).$$

I tried using an upper bound of three in each expression. For the first expression I obtained $$a_1^2x^2 + 2a_1a_2x^3.$$
For the second expression I obtained $$a_1^2x^2 + 2a_1a_2x^3 + a_2^2x^4 + 2a_2a_3x^5 + a_3^2x^6.$$
As it appears the first two terms are the same. Can we ignore the extra terms as the upper bound approaches infinity?

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\color{#C00}{a_n}x^n\tag1\\
&=\color{#C00}{a_1}x+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\color{#C00}{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}a_ka_{n-k}}x^n\tag2\\
&=x+\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n\right)^2\tag3\\[9pt]
&=x+f(x)^2\tag4
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: $f$ is the [generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) for $a_n$
$(2)$: use the recurrence for $a_n$
$(3)$: $a_1=1$ and the [Cauchy Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) of the sum in $(2)$
$(4)$: $f$ is the generating function for $a_n$

Since, $f(x)^2-f(x)+x=0$,
$$
\begin{align}
f(x)
&=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}2\tag5\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{4n-2}\binom{2n}{n}x^n\tag6
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(5)$: apply the [Quadratic Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula)
$(6)$: apply the [Generalized Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem)

Since $f$ is the generating function for $a_n$,
$$
a_n=\frac1{4n-2}\binom{2n}{n}=\frac1n\binom{2n-2}{n-1}\tag7
$$

Answer (score 2):

Instead of truncating each series, perhaps a better way to think about it is the following: what is the coefficient of $x^k$ in $(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n)^2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty a_n a_m x^{n+m}$?
You would have to add all the terms of the form $a_n a_m x^{n+m}$ where $n+m=k$.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Could you elaborate by using terms from each expression?

Answer (score 2):

The sketch below

[image: Prod_Serie_1]

should help to clear that the product of two series, in general,
(provided that they are absolutely convergent of course)
can be done by summing

- first by "rows" and then by "columns", or
- first by "columns" and then by "rows", or
- first along the inverse "diagonals" and then over them

that is
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left( {\sum\limits_{1\, \le \,k} {a_{\,k} x^{\,k} } } \right)\left( {\sum\limits_{1\, \le \,j} {b_{\,j} x^{\,j} } } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,k} {\left( {a_{\,k} x^{\,k} \left( {\sum\limits_{1\, \le \,j} {b_{\,j} x^{\,j} } } \right)} \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,j} {\left( {\left( {\sum\limits_{1\, \le \,k} {a_{\,k} x^{\,k} } } \right)b_{\,j} x^{\,j} } \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{2\, \le \,q} {\left( {\left( {\sum\limits_{1\, \le \,k} {a_{\,k} b_{\,q - k} } } \right)x^{\,q} } \right)}  \cr} 
$$

Clearly, if you put an upper bound to the sums, that is you limit to a rectangle the infinite
grid above, than in summing along the diagonals , if you go over the maximum possible exponent for $x$
you will have some terms missing.

Answer (score 1):

For generating functions, the power series are actually [formal power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series), and the product of two formal power series obeys the following rule (See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Ring_structure)):$$
\left( \sum_{n = 0}^∞ a_n x^n \right)\left( \sum_{n = 0}^∞ b_n x^n \right) = \sum_{n = 0}^∞ \left( \sum_{k = 0}^n a_k b_{n-k} \right) x^n. \tag{1}
$$
The intuition behind this rule is that if $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^∞ a_n x^n$ and $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^∞ b_n x^n$ are two power series (not formal ones) that converge absolutely, [Merten's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product#Convergence_and_Mertens'_theorem) implies that the RHS of (1) also converges and (1) holds. As for the reason why the coefficients of $x^n$ on the RHS is $\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n a_k b_{n-k}$, it is easy to see the intuition by looking for the coefficient of $x^n$ on the LHS.

Answer (score 0):

Let 
$$f_n = \frac{1}{n} \binom{2n-2}{n-1} = \frac{1}{2n - 1} \binom{2n-1}{n}$$

\begin{align}
f(x) &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_nx^n\tag{1}\\
     &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2n - 1} \binom{2n-1}{n}x^n\\
     &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2n-2)!}{n!(n-1)!}x^n\\
     &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \binom{2n-2}{n-1}x^n\tag{2}\\
     &= \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1 - 4x}\\
\end{align}

> $$x + \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_nx^n\right)\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_nx^n\right) =x + [f(x)]^2 = f(x)$$

But from equation **(1)**, 
$$[f(x)]^2 = \sum_{n=2}^\infty\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}f_if_{n-1}\right)x^n$$
Therefore, 
$$x + \sum_{n=2}^\infty\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}f_if_{n-1}\right)x^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_nx^n$$

---

An observation $f_n = \frac{1}{n} \binom{2n-2}{n-1} = \frac{(2n-2)!}{n!(n-1)!} = C_{n-1}$. Where $C_n$ is the [Catalan Number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CatalanNumber.html)